# Formatting data inside WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to format my cells inside wpf `DataGrid` control but i am having problems with it.

I am having class like this:

```
class WashItem
{
    private DateTime _Time = DateTime.Now;
    private string _Staff = "Undefined";
    private double _Price = 850;

    public string Staff { get => _Staff; set => _Staff = value; }
    public DateTime Time { get => _Time; set => _Time = value; }
    public double Price { get => _Price; set => _Price = value; }
}
```

and I am populating my datagrid like this

```
private void ReloadData()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("baza.txt");
    double ukupnaVrednost = 0;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Osoblje");
    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Vreme");
    DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("Cena");

    table.Columns.Add(col1);
    table.Columns.Add(col3);
    table.Columns.Add(col2);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        WashItem item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WashItem>(lines[i]);

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["Osoblje"] = item.Staff;
        row["Vreme"] = item.Time;
        row["Cena"] = item.Price;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        ukupnaVrednost += item.Price;
    }

    dataGridView.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();

    UkupnoOprano.Content = "Ukupno oprano vozila: " + lines.Length;
    UkupnoOpranoVrednost.Content = "Vrednost: " + ukupnaVrednost.ToString("#,##0.00");
}
```

then I have created datagrid like this

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGridView_AutoGeneratingColumn"></DataGrid>
```

and finally here is my `dataGridView_AutoGeneratingColumn` function

```
private void dataGridView_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "Cena")
    {
        ((DataGridTextColumn)e.Column).Binding.StringFormat = "#,##0.00 rsd";
    }
    else if(e.PropertyName == "Vreme")
    {
        ((DataGridTextColumn)e.Column).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

Auto generate columns function get's fired and it does enter `if` block but at the end my data is still the same - not formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need to set DataType for DataColumns, because required formats are specific to those types, and won't work for `object` type.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable
{
    Columns = 
    {
         new DataColumn("Osoblje"),
         new DataColumn("Vreme", typeof(DateTime)),
         new DataColumn("Cena", typeof(double))
    }
};
```